# jQuery Ajax if else statement not interpreting string correctly

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, if-statement

This is a frustrating one as it relates to something so basic but I'm tearing my hair out trying to figure out why it isn't working.

It's a simple Ajax call to a PHP script. When the result comes back there's an if-else statement in the callback which should give two alternative courses of action. For some reason, the if statement is being ignored, even when the string from the PHP script seems to match.

Code is below. The PHP script is returning the string 'nothing' as it should do. The `console.log` is showing that the string is being passed to the jQuery script correctly, however the if/else statement is simply displaying the string in the target `<div>` instead of hiding the `<div>` as it should do. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? I have a horrible suspicion it will be something ridiculously simple!

jQuery

```
      $.ajax({
      url: "getcompleted.php",
      type: "POST",
      data: {eMail: eMail},
      success: function(data){
        console.log(data)
        if (data == "nothing"){
          $('#completedAssessDiv').hide();
            }
        else {
          $('#completedAssessContent').html(data);
        }
      }
    });
```

PHP

```
<?php
include_once('dbconnect.php');

$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, trim($_POST['eMail']));

$run_feedback_query = "SELECT * FROM users_modules WHERE email = '$email' AND complete = '1' ORDER BY modname";
$run_feedback_check = $conn->query($run_feedback_query);
$feedback_count = $run_feedback_check -> num_rows;

if ($feedback_count > 0) {
  while ($row = $run_feedback_check -> fetch_assoc()){
         $unitdescrip = $unitcheck['mod_name'];

         echo "<div class='assignmentDetail'>" . $row['descrip'] . "</div>"; 
        }
 }


else {
 echo "nothing";
}



?>
```

Comment: `if ($.trim(data) == "nothing")`

Comment: try alert(JSON.stringify(data)) in success and see what it contains

Comment: try `console.log('#'+data+'#')` to check for white space

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should add `dataType:"text"`:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "getcompleted.php",
  type: "POST",
  data: {eMail: eMail},
  dataType:"text", // <-----add this too
```

and ofcourse you have to `trim` the text returned form the ajax call:

```
if ($.trim(data) == "nothing"){
```

Answer (score 0):

Check for any whitespace outside of the php tags

ie before `<?php`

and after `?>`

Answer (score 0):

just use `exit`  in your code and it would be better if you are not returning anything then `exit` after your code.

in your case it should be something like this.

```
else {
  echo "nothing";
}
exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Use single quotes instead of double quotes while enclosing 'nothing' as follows:

In JQuery:

```
if (data == 'nothing'){
```

In PHP:

```
echo 'nothing';
```